# creating complete historical timeline from overlapping intervals

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table which contain a code, from, to and hour. The problem is that i have overlapping dates in the intervals. Instead of it i want to create a complete historical timeline. So whe the code is identical and there is a overlap it should sum the hours like in the desired result.

** table **

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| code | from           | to             | hours      |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 2013-05-01     | 2013-09-30     | 37         |
| 1    | 2013-05-01     | 2014-02-28     | 10         |
| 1    | 2013-10-01     | 9999-12-31     | 5          |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

desired result:

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| code | from           | to             | hours      |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 2013-05-01     | 2013-09-30     | 47         |
| 1    | 2013-10-01     | 2014-02-28     | 15         |
| 1    | 2014-02-29     | 9999-12-31     | 5          |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please explain what the results should be if you have 2 overlapping intervals A-C and B-D, both with a value of 10. Would you get 3 rows in the result? A-B, value 10, B-C, value 20, and C-D, value 10?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the above from and to is closed intervals so in case overlapping like you mention i guess it should be 5 rows since B and C is overlapping by 1 day. does this make sense?

Comment: @PeterPik . . . Can there be more than one overlapping row?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes there can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( code, "FROM", "TO", hours ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2013-05-01', DATE '2013-09-30', 37 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2013-05-01', DATE '2014-02-28', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2013-10-01', DATE '9999-12-31',  5 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT code,
         dt AS "FROM",
         LEAD( dt ) OVER ( PARTITION BY code ORDER BY dt ASC, value DESC, ROWNUM ) AS "TO",
         hours
  FROM   (
    SELECT code,
           dt,
           SUM( hours * value ) OVER ( PARTITION BY code ORDER BY dt ASC, VALUE DESC ) AS hours,
           value
    FROM   table1
    UNPIVOT ( dt FOR value IN ( "FROM" AS 1, "TO" AS -1 ) )
  )
)
WHERE  "FROM" + 1 < "TO";
```

**Results**:

```
CODE FROM       TO         HOURS
---- ---------- ---------- -----
   1 2013-05-01 2013-09-30    47
   1 2013-10-01 2014-02-28    15
   1 2014-02-28 9999-12-31     5
```